# Using ModelMapper in kotlin spring boot

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, modelmapper

In few of my projects in spring boot I have used ModelMapper (https://www.baeldung.com/java-modelmapper). However now I am writing an app using **Kotlin**, and I couldn't find any solution that would be easier to use for converting objects from one class to another. Let's say that we have two classes like these:

`class Test(val name: String, val size: Int)`

`class AnotherTest(val name: String, val size: Int, val id: String)`

If these classes were written in Java, we could convert AnotherTest to Test like this:

```
//   some class definition with modelMapper of ModelMapper type field, methods
    
    public Test convertToTest(AnotherTest anotherTest) {
        Test testInstance = this.modelMapper.map(anotherTest, Test.class);
    }
```

I think using something like Test.class is illegal in Kotlin, so how should I write this function in Kotlin?

When I tried it myself by writing it the same way as in java:

```
fun convertToTest(another: AnotherTest): Test = this.modelMapper.map(another, Test.class)
```

I am getting 2 errors:

```
Name expected
Expecting ')'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's illegal`*` but, until cops will find you, you can use for example

```
fun convertToTest(anotherTest: AnotherTest) = modelMapper.map(anotherTest, Test::class.java)
```

Read more here:

- [Calling Java from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html)

Also [reified types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) may be interesting for you

---

`*` just joking it's not illegal :)